# Trouble with Doubly Linked Drop-out Stack

Tags: java, reference, stack, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to make a drop-out stack using a doubly linked list. Everything works well EXCEPT the drop out functionality. When I test it, the bottom of the stack is still there. The problem is likely in my push method. I'm thinking there's some detail about the references I'm missing somewhere.

I'm using node class to hold the elements. Node class contains self references for previous and next node and has methods for accessing and setting these. `getNext()`, `setNext()`, `getPrevious()`, `setNext()`
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class lDOStack<T>
{
    private int count;  
    private LinearNode<T> top, bottom;
private static final int LIMIT = 10;

/**
 * Creates an empty stack.
 */
public lDOStack()
{
    count = 0;
    top = bottom = null;
}

/**
 * Adds the specified element to the top of this stack.
 * If number of elements is greater than limit after push,
 * bottom of stack is lost.
 * @param element element to be pushed on stack
 */

public void push(T element)
{

    LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);
    temp.setNext(top);


    if (isEmpty())
    {
        bottom = temp;  //Reference to first element added. 
    }

    else if (size() == 1)
    {
        bottom.setPrevious(temp);
    }

    else if (size() > 0) 
    {
        top.setPrevious(temp);
    }

    top = temp;
    count++;


    if (size() > LIMIT)             //Bottom should drop out but doesn't.
    {
        count--;
        bottom = bottom.getPrevious();

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `size()` implementation?

Comment: Also, along with `bottom = bottom.getPrevious();` you should make a call to `bottom.getNext().setPrevious(null);` and `bottom.getNext().setNext(null);` and `bottom.setNext(null);`.

Comment: Nailed it. This was the problem.  Thanks!                                                                                                 size() implementation and other standard methods like isEmpty() are present. I just didn't post them since they aren't really relevant. I know they work.